# Flutter: If constraints go down and sizes go up, then why does Expanded exist?

Tags: flutter, layout

I am trying to understand how the Flutter layout system works.

[I read in the docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints) that, on Flutter, "constraints go down and sizes go up", meaning, the parent tells the child what its sizes contraints are, and the child tells the parent their chozen size.

And then I read the definition of the [Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) widget:

> A widget that expands a child of a Row, Column, or Flex so that the child fills the available space.

Question: Doesn't `Expanded` break the above rule? My understanding is that a parent shouldn't tell its children its size, and that's what `Expanded` is doing. Also, without the `Expanded`, the children would already know its constraints and they could be 100% width and height if they wanted.

What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I am the author of that article in the docs.

> My understanding is that a parent shouldn't tell its children its size

Not exactly. The parent tells its children the **constraints**, which are the min and max size each child can have. So the child **cannot** have any size it wants. It must be within those constraints.

If the parent tells a child it can have a minimum of 80 pixels and a maximum of 80 pixels, then yes, the parent is in practice telling the child its size, as the only answer the child can give here is 80 pixels. This is called a "tight" constraint.

That's exactly what the `Expanded` does. It tells the child it must have at min and at max the same size as the `Expanded`, so that the child can only "decide" to have the same size of the `Expanded`.

By the way, if instead of the `Expanded` you use a `Flexible` widget, it will tell the child to have at max the same size as the `Flexible`, but the min will be set at 0. This is called a "loose" constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Let's understand this with the help of few scenarios:

**1. We fixed the size of the parent but not the child:**
Child will takeover the whole space provided by the parent. If there are many child they will adjust themselves according to parent widget constraints.

**2. We fixed the size of the child but not the parent:**
Child will occupy the space according to its content.

**3. If we Wrap the child by "Expanded" widget:**
The expanded widget let the child to occupy all the remaining space present in the Row, Column or Flex wherever it is being called.