# How expanded give bounded constrians to listview as a children of column(column->Expanded->Listview)

Tags: flutter

Case1:
Consider this code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(const Foo());
}

class Foo extends StatelessWidget {
  const Foo({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      builder: (context, child) => Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            ListView(), // This will cause the error
          ],            // Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.
        ),              // Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container. In this case, a vertical
      ),                // viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand.
    );
  }
}
```

Case2:
But When the listview is wrapped inside Expanded widget it does't give that error for example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(const Foo());
}

class Foo extends StatelessWidget {
  const Foo({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      builder: (context, child) => Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(child: ListView()), // NO issue everything is fine
          ],            
        ),           
      ),                
    );
  }
}
```

Now i the question arises that as the Column give unbounded height(in case1) constrains to listview and as the listview want to be of infinite height which raiase the unbounded height error but when the listview is wrapped inside expanded it doesn't give unbounded height error that means that the expanded give the listview bounded constrains.
But how does expanded decides the constrains as the column still gives him unbounded height.

This question is realted to  the answer given here :https://stackoverflow.com/a/73571651/19801146 as i can't comment there so i asked new.

I readied the Api docs of column, expanded and the understanding constrains article to understand that why this happened but not able to find the answer.

And if anyone explain me the flutter layout in detail i will be so thankful as i readied the layout article but not able to wrap me head around that.

Comment: make 'shrinkWrap:true', Expanded Widget inside ListView takes infinite height so better to use SizedBox.

Answer (score 0):

Refering to the same Q&A you´re talking about ([Flutter: If constraints go down and sizes go up, then why does Expanded exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73311516/flutter-if-constraints-go-down-and-sizes-go-up-then-why-does-expanded-exist/73571651#73571651)):

> If the parent tells a child it can have a minimum of 80 pixels and a
> maximum of 80 pixels, then yes, the parent is in practice telling the
> child its size, as the only answer the child can give here is 80
> pixels. This is called a "tight" constraint.
>
> That's exactly what the Expanded does. It tells the child it must have
> at min and at max the same size as the Expanded, so that the child can
> only "decide" to have the same size of the Expanded.

So, basically, if you use only ListView or any of its variations such as ListView.builder they´ll want to expand to unbounded height (that´s why you should use `shrinkwrap = true` when using ListView inside of Flexible widgets), but if you use Expanded then it´ll take the parent size (height in this case) and use it to constraint the ListView´s height.

Comment: Well as you said expanded take the parent size ( height in this case is infinite isn't it).